# Android best practice : 2 activities or 1 activity with multiple layouts?

Tags: android

I have two main screens in my app : main view and settings. Should there be two activities for that ? Or should 1 main activity, 2 layouts and I hide/show them when necessary ?

Answer (score 2):

Two activities.
Acceptable option is one activity with multiple fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I would also say two activities.. It really depends on your goals both user experience wise and functionally.  Of course paying close attention to how they interact with each other (`startActivity` vs `startActivityForResult`) and `savedInstanceState` s

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fragments (1 for Main, 1 for settings). For more information go to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use two different activities that extends an abstacts Activity created by you, in which you'll add all the custom features you need on both activities.